# Constructing a bounded set of real numbers with exactly three limit points

Tags: real-analysis

Credit for the problem goes to Baby Rudin, Chapter 2, Exercise 5.

We are to construct a bounded set of real numbers with exactly three limit points. Seeing as there are few "computation"-tasks in the book, I haven't really had a chance to build up intuition the way I am used to, however, loeoking at the text in Topology, it seems like I have to get used to this.

I let $X$ be the metric space $\mathbf{R}$. I let $E$ be its subset $\{(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon),(2-\epsilon,2+\epsilon),(3-\epsilon,3+\epsilon)\}$ for small $\epsilon > 0$. Clearly, $1, 2$ and $3$ are limit points of $E$. However, if I have understood the concept of a limit point (and a neighborhood) correcly, so is $1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. I'm having a hard time seeing how I am to limit the number of limit points (no pun intended.)

Comment: $\{0,1/2,1/3,\cdots\}$ has exactly one limit point. Make two additional "disjoint copies" of it.

Comment: Where is the limit point of that set?

Comment: The point $0$.${}$

Comment: $0$ is a limit point of the given set if every neighborhood of $0$ contains a point which is in the given set, if I have understood correctly. If the neighborhood is $N_\epsilon(0)$, with $\epsilon < \frac{1}{2}$, isn't that a contradiction? (Not claiming you are wrong, I am aware that I am misunderstanding some concept here.)

Comment: The (infinite) set is $\{ 1/n \mid n=1,2,3,\cdots\}\cup\{0\}$. Your nhood contains some point in the set since there is a positive integer $N$ with $1/N<\epsilon$.

Comment: Ah, of course, I blundered. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take the set
$$\left\{\sin{2\pi n\over3}+{1\over n}\ \biggm|\>n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}\right\}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $$a_n=k+\dfrac{1}{n},\qquad k\equiv n(\mod3).$$ Then the sequence $(a_n)$ has exactly three limt poins $\{0, 1, 2\}$.

Answer (score -1):

The Sequence $a(n) = sin (0.5 n(\pi))$

Comment: No limit points here. Your set is just $ \{  -1,0,1 \} $ and a finite set has no limit points